# R&T toilet fill valve slow filling

Tags: plumbing, toilet

There is a bottom fill R&T fill valve in my compact cistern. I’m sure it’s for a high pressure supply and mine is connected to a low pressure, my cistern takes forever to fill. Is there anyway of changing this valve to make it quicker?